# Is there anything like exportmany in mef?

Tags: c#, .net, inversion-of-control, mef

I have some instances that will be exported at runtime like below.

```
public static IEnumerable<IFileMetaDataProvider> _providers;
    [ExportMany(typeof(IFileMetaDataProvider))] 
    public static IEnumerable<IFileMetaDataProvider> Providers {
        get {
            if (_providers == null) {
                _providers = new IFileMetaDataProvider[2];
            }
            return _providers;
        }
    }
```

The instances that will be exported will be determined at runtime,and I don't want to code for every single instance (cuz the instances might take dependencies of other exported interface-typed instances:( ),could anyone tell me how can I achieve this in comment way or programming way?

Answer (score 1):

You have the relationship between imports and exports inverted. You want to have any class that implements **IFileMetaDataProvider** to also **Export** that interface as well.

Your code that consumes these implementations would then look like this

```
[ImportMany(typeof(IFileMetaDataProvider))] 
public static IEnumerable<IFileMetaDataProvider> Providers
```

The **Import** attribute will throw an exception if multiple components export the same value. **ImportMany** will import one or more components that have a matching **Export** attribute.

If the classes that implement **IFileMetaDataProvider** also have **Import** or **ImportMany** attributes, those imports will be satisfied by MEF during the composition as well. As long as there are matching exports in the catalog, you don’t need to worry about dependencies for your imported components.

Comment: Thanks for your answer,I have no question about how component get multiple exported instances,what I'm wondering,is there any way to export a set of sequence of objects just like what ImportMany attribute do while acquiring a set of sequence of objects?I want to get this feature for some reasons,I'll apprecial